# Some Audio Files not working in some android devices

Tags: android

I have created on application for animal sound. It plays the sound on touch of image. It is working properly in my samsung galaxy ACE. But It doesn't work properly in some devices like HTC Flyer, motorola. I mean I can't hear sound for some animal.For some animal it is working properly in all devices.

FYI: For playing sound I have used soundpool. I have used .MP3 and .WAV files.

Answer (score 0):

Media codecs that are not guaranteed to be available on all Android platform versions

[refer this](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: What's the solution for this?

Comment: @amipatel change your audio file bit rate which one is not supporting.

Comment: Which the best audio rate that can work in all devices? My current audio files(which are not working) bit rate is 20 bit, 32 bit etc

Comment: use 8- and 16-bit linear PCM (rates up to limit of hardware)

Comment: my working files bit rates are 352 kbps, 88 kbps, 128 kbps etc. Also some 20 kbps and 32 kbps files are also working in all devices.  but Some files are not working in some devices.